# How to convert or assign the object to Variant type in vc 6.0

Tags: visual-c++, wmi, visual-c++-6

I need to assign the object of IWbemClassObject to the Variant or how can i convert this object to variant type.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IWbemClassObject* p = ...;  // initialized somehow

VARIANT v;
V_VT(&v) = VT_UNKNOWN;
(V_UNKNOWN(&v) = p)->AddRef();
```